# preg_match: number-alphabets and commas only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do I write a regular expression which matches number-alphabets and commas only?

I came out with this one below but it doesnt work - it accepts other punctuation marks as well!

```
# check for matches number-alphabets and commas only
  if(!preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9\,])/', $cst_value))
  {
   $error = true;
   echo '<error elementid="usr_username" message="'.$cst_name.' - please use number-alphabets and commas only."/>';
  }
```

Many thanks,
Lau

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$/
```

You need the start `^` and end `$` of string anchors. Without them the regex engine will look for any of those characters in the string and if it finds one, it will call it a day and say there's a match. With the anchors, it forces the engine to look at the whole string. Basically:

- `/[a-zA-Z0-9,]+/` matches if *any* of the characters are alphanumeric + comma.
- `/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$/` matches if *all* of the characters are alphanumeric + comma.

Comment: i use preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","", $string); to strip only numeric and character only. :) thank you for your idea.

Comment: I want to match comma (and preceding alphanumeric chars) only if there are some alphanumeric chars after comma, else leave comma and all preceding chars. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-z,]+$/i', $cst_value)) {
  // valid input..contains only alphabet,number and comma.
}else{
  // invalid
}
```

We pass the following to preg_match : `/^[0-9a-z,]+$/i`

Explanation:

- `/` : regex delimiters.
- `^` : start anchor
- `[..]` : Char class
- `0-9` : any digit
- `a-z` : any alphabet
- `,` : a comma. comma is not a regex
  metachar, so you need not escape it
- `+` : quantifier for one or more. If
  an empty input is considered valid,
  change `+` to `*`
- `$` : end anchor
- `i` : to make the matching case
  insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Well this adds a couple more characters like underscore

```
/^[\w,]*$/
```

But this should work

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*$/
```

Comment: `\w` doesn't include whitespaces.

Comment: hmm thought the \w did whitespace as well but after looking it doesn't. Thanks guys learning everyday