# Only Alphanumeric and one special charcter regex in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$str = 'test-test-test-test\\50-test-37447';
     if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9-]/',$str,$matches)){
         echo "<pre>true";print_r($matches);echo "</pre>";
     }else{
         echo "<pre>false";print_r($matches);echo "</pre>";
     }
```

It always return true? Where I am wrong?

Comment: Missing anchors: `^` & `$`.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787495/preg-match-number-alphabets-and-commas-only

Comment: Your attempted change to the code makes it match my answer and hence _will_ work. Reverting to the original question. Please don't change questions in a manner that invalidates answers. Especially don't change them in a manner that makes the entire problem disappear :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns true because your regex calls for any one character from that set (so `t` from the start is the first match).

If you want the *entire* string to be only made up of those characters, use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$
```

The `^` and `$` markers indicate start and end of string respectively, and the `*` means zero or more of the preceding "object". Hence it means the entire string must be made up of zero or more of the character set you've specified.

This causes the `\` character to fail the match in your test string.