# How to validate username in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want username validation in php. I just want to allow user to type ABC[ English characters] only. I do not want  allow to user to type ``` []{}()//,.<>*~``^ ```.

I have this code :

```
 if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,}$/', $_POST['username'])){
        $username_err = "<div class='alert alert-danger text-capitalize'>
                                    type alphanumaric in first name only</div>";
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Comment: If i type any of these []{}()//,.<>*~`^ in username filed it must  not be allowed to user

Comment: @jawad altaf you regular expressions is wrong it mean username must start by number between 0 to 9 and must ended by number between 2 to 9

Comment: @bahram then kindly tell me the right way to validate

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787495/preg-match-number-alphabets-and-commas-only

Comment: @JawadAltaf see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regular expression is wrong in this case, simply add this regular expressions

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $_POST['username']))
```

if you want to not allow the number too test this one:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $_POST['username']))
```

Comment: Please explain why OPs regexp is incorrect

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that regex mean username must start by number between 0 to 9 and must ended by number between 2 to 9 but he want to make a regex that allow just English characters